# selenium cucumber driver.quit() is stuck when I am using saucelabs

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, saucelabs

I am new to selenium. I have been running given selenium test scripts always using below and never I had issues:

- IntelliJ
- Selenium + cucumber + Java
- I am running my test cases using Sauce Labs> sauce connect (Tunnel Identifier).

But suddenly for the last 2 days, I have been facing an issue, that is :
My script is stuck at the driver.quit() in @After, for hours no Error or anything. IntelliJ is showing the script as running (but not seeing any test progress in the console).

**Note**: These scripts are working fine when I run locally, but the issue is when I am running with sauce labs.

code is:

@After

```
public void tearDown(Scenario scenario) {
    if (driver()!=null) {
        System.out.println("Printing till here"); 
        driver().quit();  
        System.out.println("Not printing");
    }
```

After this intellij script is running, and no error in the console. Not sure what is happening here.

Please guide me on how to fix this one.

I tried different ways, but no luck;

- try - finally
- try - catch
- using both driver().close(); driver().quit();